# Convert a virtual-key code to a unicode character - WinApi C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to convert a virtual-key code to a unicode character. The virtual-key codes are received from a low level keyboard hook.

```
LRESULT __stdcall hook_callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
                const auto kbd_hook = reinterpret_cast<KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam);

                BYTE state[256];
                GetKeyboardState(state);

                WCHAR key_buffer[2];
                ToUnicode(kbd_hook->vkCode, kbd_hook->scanCode, state, key_buffer, 2, 0);
                // handle key_buffer...
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This works fine except for the fact that `Shift` and `Caps Lock` are not taken into account. Pressing `Shift + 1` will result in `1`, instead of the expected `!` (assuming the locale is US). However, if I fill the state buffer by individually getting each key, it works as expected:

```
BYTE state[256];
for (SHORT i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        const SHORT key_state = GetKeyState(i);

        // Right shifts the high order bit by 8 to avoid a narrowing
        // conversion from SHORT to BYTE.
        state[i] = (key_state >> 8) | (key_state & 1);
}
```

If I fill the `state` buffer like so, pressing `Shift + 1` will result in `!` as expected.

Why does `GetKeyState()` work but `GetKeyboardState()` doesn't?

Comment: `WM_KEYDOWN` reports (virtual) key presses. If you want to handle characters, you should intercept `WM_CHAR` instead. Keyboard input is a complex matter. Trying to re-implement it is a painful exercise. Be prepared for failure.

Comment: @IInspectable especially in a low level hook, where information is received in pieces and difficult to put back together

Comment: This is why there are two keyboard hooks.  WH_KEYBOARD_LL is easy to implement but cannot reliably convert virtual keys.  WH_KEYBOARD does not have this problem because the hook callback operates inside the process that is in the foreground.  That GetKeyState() is a workaround is pretty odd, but might have something to do with this code running inside a console mode app.

Comment: @HansPassant It is not running inside a console application, but rather an empty windows subsystem application.

Comment: GetKeyState() requires a message loop to operate correctly.  Presumably it can figure out that GetMessage() was never called, so falls back to GetAsyncKeyState().

Comment: There is a message loop in the application, it just doesn't have a GUI.

Comment: @HansPassant It most definitely doesn't fallback to `GetAsyncKeyState` as holding shift and pressing multiple numbers all result in the respective special characters. `GetAsyncKeyState` takes previous calls into account.